# How to detect when a block is duplicated

Tags: wordpress-gutenberg

I want to give my blocks a unique ID that remains the same along post updates.

```
edit: class extends Component {
   constructor(props) {
      if(!props.blockID) this.props.setAttributes({ blockID: 'blk'+(new Date()).getTime() });
   }
}
```

But when the user duplicates de block, causes the ID being twice on the page.

I need some way to detect the duplication and give a new ID to the block.

Thanks.

Comment: Could you just reference the clientId instead? this.props.clientId (I think it's always unique)

Comment: @Rice_Crisp I believe the client ID for a block changes after page refresh.

Answer (score 5):

I hope this would help You

```js
import { createHigherOrderComponent } from '@wordpress/compose';
import { useEffect } from '@wordpress/element';
import { simpleHash } from '../../helpers/simple-hash';
import { v1 as uuidv1 } from 'uuid';
import { select } from '@wordpress/data';
import { addFilter } from '@wordpress/hooks';

const isBlockIdReserved = ( blockId, clientId ) => {
    const blocksClientIds = select( 'core/block-editor' ).getClientIdsWithDescendants();
    return blocksClientIds.some( ( _clientId ) => {
        const { blockId: _blockId } = select( 'core/block-editor' ).getBlockAttributes( _clientId );
        return clientId !== _clientId && blockId === _blockId;
    } );
};

const addBlockEditAttributes = createHigherOrderComponent( ( BlockEdit ) => {
    return ( props ) => {
        const { attributes, setAttributes, clientId } = props;

        const {
            blockId,
        } = attributes;

        const setFreshBlockId = () => {
            const freshBlockId = simpleHash( uuidv1() );
            setAttributes( {
                blockId: freshBlockId,
            } );
        };

        useEffect( () => {
            if ( ! blockId ) {
                setFreshBlockId();
                return;
            }

            if ( isBlockIdReserved( blockId, clientId ) ) {
                // eslint-disable-next-line no-console
                console.log( `Block with id '${ blockId }' already exists. Regenerating...`, blockId );
                setFreshBlockId();
            }
        }, [ blockId ] );

        return <BlockEdit { ...props } />;
    };
}, 'addBlockEditAttributes' );



addFilter(
    'editor.BlockEdit',
    'my-plugin/add-block-edit-attributes',
    addBlockEditAttributes
);
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Looks really well. I will try it soon. Thanks. It's still useful despite the time that has passed since my question.

Comment: Thanks a lot! This helps me to detect duplicated block.

Comment: This pointed me in the correct direction since I used an identical approach, but tried it in the edit function of the block – which doesn’t get called on duplication. By using a filter it worked fine.

Answer (score 3):

I have done something similar before. The way I got it to work was to do two things:

1. Save the `id` as a block attribute (so it stays the same across renders/post updates). If the block's `id` is `undefined`, it is a new block, so you can set the `id`.
2. As each block renders, check its `id` against all the previous `id`s. If a block with that ID already exists, it is a duplicate.

Something like this should get you started:

```js
let uniqueIds = [];

const ComponentEdit = ({
    attributes,
    setAttributes,
}) => {
    const {
        uuid,
    } = attributes;

    useEffect(() => {
        let id = uuid;

        if (!id || uniqueIds.includes(id)) {
            id = getUniqueIDFunc(); // Set your unique ID here

            setAttributes({uuid: id});
        }

        uniqueIds.push(id);
    }, []);
    
    return (
        <div id={ uuid }></div>
    );
};
```

Comment: It's still usefull for me, Phil, many thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The answer of Phil is perfect. Here is the full code of my project:

```js
/**
 * @info Add setting controls to the Inspector Panels or the Toolbar
 */
var sneeitClientIds = new Set();
const sneeitBlocksAttributesControls = createHigherOrderComponent((BlockEdit) => {
    return (props) => {
        const {attributes, setAttributes, clientId} = props;
        
        let { sneeitClientId } = attributes;

        // you should have this to prevent infinite rerender update
        useEffect(()=>{ // every time when rerender happens, reset the sneeitClientIds
            if (!sneeitClientId || sneeitClientIds.has(sneeitClientId))  {
                setAttributes({sneeitClientId: clientId})                
                sneeitClientIds.add(clientId)
            } else {
                sneeitClientIds.add(sneeitClientId)
            }
        });
        

        return (
            <>
                <BlockEdit {...props} />
            </>
        );
    };
}, 'sneeitBlocksAttributesControls');
 
wp.hooks.addFilter(
    'editor.BlockEdit',
    'sneeit-blocks/apperance-controls',
    sneeitBlocksAttributesControls
);
```